# Is there a way to combine size based on a variable and input_slider in ggvis?

Tags: r, slider, ggvis

Using a minor modification to the code in the [ggvis basics](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/ggvis-basics.html) and [ggvis interactivity](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html) pages, I have the following two code snippets:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~mpg, ~disp) %>% 
  layer_points(size=~vs) %>%
  scale_numeric("size", range = c(50,500))

mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~mpg, ~disp) %>%
  layer_points(size := input_slider(50, 500, value = 50))
```

The first generates a plot:

[image]

And the second generates a similar plot where point size is controlled by the slider.

What I am looking for is how do I combine the two? That is, how can I have a relative size determined by a variable, and the range of those possible sizes determined by a slider?

It seems as though something like the following is what is needed, but `range` can't take `input_slider` as an assignment (`domain` can, but that doesn't achieve the desired results.)

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggvis(~mpg, ~disp) %>% 
  layer_points(size:=~vs) %>% 
  scale_numeric("size", clamp = TRUE,
                range = input_slider(50, 500, map = function(x) c(x, 10*x))
  )
```

**Question: how can I have a relative size determined by a variable, and the range of those possible sizes determined by a slider?**